# how to set bound property in google map in react?

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, react-google-maps

could you please me how to show polylines on viewport using `bounds` or `getBounds` properties?

currently my `polyline` are visible but I need to `zoomout` . I want to use bound property to show my line on viewport without zoomout.

here is my code

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vagomb

one solution is to reduce the `zoom level` `8` to `6`  it shows some part of line .

but I don't want to use this solution.

using `bound`  I want to do that.

```
this.setState({
        bounds: null,
        polyLines: [
          { lat: 28.4911778, lng: 77.080109 },
          { lat: 28.49094725, lng: 79.07986154 },
          { lat: 28.49075711, lng: 80.08011527 },
          { lat: 28.4905529, lng: 81.08038778 },
          { lat: 27.49076661, lng: 84.08063851 }
        ],
        center: {
          lat: 29.4911717,
          lng: 77.0800426
        },
        markers: [],
        onMapMounted: ref => {
          refs.map = ref;
        },
        onBoundsChanged: () => {
          this.setState({
            bounds: refs.map.getBounds(),
            center: refs.map.getCenter()
          });
        }

      });
```

any update ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to bound the polyline then use `bounds.extend` to calculate the bounds and then fit it on map.

```
const bounds = new window.google.maps.LatLngBounds();
props.polyLines.map(x => {
    bounds.extend(new window.google.maps.LatLng(x.lat, x.lng));
});
map && map.fitBounds(bounds)
```

**Here, I have updated your code.**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-google-maps-bounds

Hope, This will work for you!